# npm error: No matching version found for @storybook/client-api@6.2.9

Tags: npm, npm-install, storybook

I am getting the following error when running npm install on my project:

```
> npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @storybook/client-api@6.2.9.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/naresh/.npm/_logs/2021-04-23T06_13_26_855Z-debug.log
```

I know that @storybook/client-api@6.2.9 has been released to npm, so why am I getting this error? I am running npm version 7.10.0.

**Edit**

1. This is a fresh install. There is no package-lock.json file.
2. I ran `npm cache verify` to verify that cache is clean.
3. yarn has no issues with this project. Runs very smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error corrected itself the next day! I did not changed a thing. All I can say is that npm was behaving a bit flaky.